# CreateJS: interaction between two timelines in different js files

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have two timelines in two different js files, I need them to talk to each other via JS in an html file. Specifically I need the pink button `top.js` to replay the timeline of `bottom.js`.

I have a working button in `top.js` file correctly triggering the function `actionClickHandler` in the html file, but this function is not affecting the 2nd js file (`bottom.js`. I tried `stage.gotoAndPlay(1);` in my function in the js in the html page, I get the error: `stage.gotoAndPlay is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I talk to the timeline in `bottom.js` from a script in the html file?

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xxt5Wr6ZLNV6hQ6WALyM?p=preview)

bottom.js and top.js are js output from adobe animate cc, I'm trying to layer two html5 timelines on top of one another and have interaction between them basically.

Here's my relevant js in the html file:

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  exportRoot = new lib.bottomfile();

  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  stage.update();
  stage.enableMouseOver();

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}


var lib2, canvas2, stage2, exportRoot2;

function init2() {

  canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  exportRoot2 = new lib2.topfile();

  stage2 = new createjs.Stage(canvas2);
  stage2.addChild(exportRoot2);
  stage2.update();
  stage.enableMouseOver();

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib2.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage2);
}


function pageLoadedHandler() {  
    init();  
    init2(); 
}  

function actionClickHandler() {  
  console.log("Triggered from inside html function actionClickHandler"); 
  stage.gotoAndPlay(1);
  stage.update();
}
```

Here's top.js:

```
 (function (lib2, img, cjs, ss) {

    var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
    lib2.webFontTxtFilters = {}; 

    // lib2rary properties:
    lib2.properties = {
        width: 550,
        height: 400,
        fps: 24,
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        webfonts: {},
        manifest: []
    };



    lib2.webfontAvailable = function(family) { 
        lib2.properties.webfonts[family] = true;
        var txtFilters = lib2.webFontTxtFilters && lib2.webFontTxtFilters[family] || [];
        for(var f = 0; f < txtFilters.length; ++f) {
            txtFilters[f].updateCache();
        }
    };
    // symbols:



    (lib2.txt = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
        this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

        // Layer 1
        this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AgEBSQgHgDgDgFQgEgEgBgIIgBgYIAAg0IgPAAIAAgaIAPAAIAAgZIAfgTIAAAsIAXAAIAAAaIgXAAIAAAwIABASQAAABAAAAQAAABABAAQAAABABAAQAAABABAAQACACADAAQAFAAAIgDIADAZQgLAFgPAAQgJAAgFgDg");
        this.shape.setTransform(80.5,15.5);

        this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_1.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AgnA/IAAh6IAfAAIAAARQAIgMAEgEQAGgEAIAAQALAAALAGIgKAdQgJgFgHAAQgHAAgFADQgCAEgDAKQgDAKAAAeIAAAmg");
        this.shape_1.setTransform(72.8,17.4);

        this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_2.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AguA2QgLgKAAgQQAAgLAFgIQAFgIAJgDQAKgEAQgDQAVgFAKgDIAAgEQAAgJgGgEQgEgEgLAAQgJAAgEADQgFAEgEAIIgdgFQAEgSANgJQAMgJAYAAQAUAAALAGQALAFAEAIQAEAIAAAVIAAAlQAAAQACAIQABAIAFAJIggAAIgEgKIgBgEQgJAIgJAEQgHAFgLAAQgUAAgLgLgAAAAHQgNADgEADQgHAEAAAHQAAAHAFAFQAFAFAIAAQAHAAAJgFQAFgFACgGQABgFABgLIAAgHg");
        this.shape_2.setTransform(60.6,17.5);

        this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_3.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AgEBSQgHgDgDgFQgEgEgBgIIgBgYIAAg0IgPAAIAAgaIAPAAIAAgZIAfgTIAAAsIAXAAIAAAaIgXAAIAAAwIABASQAAACADACQACACADAAQAFAAAIgDIADAZQgLAFgPAAQgJAAgFgDg");
        this.shape_3.setTransform(49.9,15.5);

        this.shape_4 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_4.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AglA2QgPgKgFgSIAhgFQADAKAGAFQAGAFAKAAQANAAAGgFQAFgDAAgGQAAgDgDgDQgCgCgJgCQgmgJgKgHQgPgIAAgSQAAgQANgLQAMgMAbAAQAYAAAMAJQANAIAEAQIgfAGQgCgHgFgEQgGgEgJAAQgMAAgGAEQgDACAAAEQAAAEADACQAEAEAZAGQAaAGAKAIQALAHAAAQQAAARgPAMQgOANgcAAQgXAAgPgLg");
        this.shape_4.setTransform(39,17.5);

        this.shape_5 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_5.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AgsArQgNgRAAgaQAAgcARgSQAQgSAYAAQAaAAAQATQAQASAAAkIhRAAQAAAPAIAIQAIAIAJAAQAIAAAFgEQAFgEADgKIAhAGQgGASgOAJQgOAKgUAAQgfAAgPgWgAAZgJQAAgOgHgIQgHgHgLAAQgIAAgHAIQgHAHAAAOIAvAAIAAAAg");
        this.shape_5.setTransform(25.9,17.5);

        this.shape_6 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_6.graphics.f("#FFFFFF").s().p("AAjBWIgZgmQgLgUgFgFQgFgFgFgCQgGgCgMAAIgHAAIAABIIgjAAIAAiqIBJAAQAaAAAMAEQANAFAHAMQAIAMAAAPQAAATgMANQgLAKgXADQAMAHAHAIQAHAIANAUIAVAigAgpgLIAaAAQAXAAAGgCQAGgDAEgFQADgFAAgIQAAgIgEgGQgFgFgJgCIgXAAIgbAAg");
        this.shape_6.setTransform(11.5,15.2);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_6},{t:this.shape_5},{t:this.shape_4},{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape_2},{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(1));

    }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
    p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,86.6,30.9);


    (lib2.pink = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
        this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

        // Layer 1
        this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape.graphics.f("#FF00FF").s().p("ApMDHQg9AAAAg7IAAkWQAAg9A9AAISaAAQA7AAAAA9IAAEWQAAA7g7AAg");
        this.shape.setTransform(65,20);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

    }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
    p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,130,40);


    (lib2.myBtn = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
        this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

        // Layer 2
        this.instance = new lib2.txt();
        this.instance.setTransform(64.3,19,1,1,0,0,0,43.3,15.4);
        new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.instance, 0, 1, 1);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1).to({alpha:0.801},0).wait(3));

        // Layer 1
        this.instance_1 = new lib2.pink();
        this.instance_1.setTransform(65,20,1,1,0,0,0,65,20);
        new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.instance_1, 0, 1, 1);

        this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape.graphics.f("#FF00FF").s().p("ApMDHQg9AAAAg7IAAkWQAAg9A9AAISaAAQA7AAAAA9IAAEWQAAA7g7AAg");
        this.shape.setTransform(65,20);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1,p:{alpha:1}}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1,p:{alpha:0.801}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape}]},2).wait(1));

    }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
    p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,130,40);


    // stage content:



    (lib2.topfile = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
        this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

        // timeline functions:
        this.frame_1 = function() {
            this.myBtn.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

            function fl_MouseClickHandler()
            {
                actionClickHandler();
            console.log("clicked in Timeline");
                alert("Mouse clicked");
                // End your custom code
            }
        }
        this.frame_4 = function() {
            this.stop();
        }

        // actions tween:
        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(1).call(this.frame_1).wait(3).call(this.frame_4).wait(1));

        // Layer 1
        this.myBtn = new lib2.myBtn();
        this.myBtn.setTransform(466,360,1,1,0,0,0,65,20);
        new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.myBtn, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib2.myBtn(), 3);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.myBtn).wait(5));

    }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
    p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(676,540,130,40);

    })(lib2 = lib2||{}, images2 = images2||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
    var lib2, images2, createjs, ss;
```

Here's bottom.js:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
lib.webFontTxtFilters = {}; 

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    webfonts: {},
    manifest: []
};



lib.webfontAvailable = function(family) { 
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;
    var txtFilters = lib.webFontTxtFilters && lib.webFontTxtFilters[family] || [];
    for(var f = 0; f < txtFilters.length; ++f) {
        txtFilters[f].updateCache();
    }
};
// symbols:



(lib.myBlueCircle = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#0000FF").s().p("AiMCNQg6g7gBhSQABhSA6g6QA6g6BSgBQBSABA7A6QA7A6gBBSQABBSg7A7Qg7A7hSgBQhSABg6g7g");
    this.shape.setTransform(20,20);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,40,40);


// stage content:
(lib.bottomfile = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_9 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(9).call(this.frame_9).wait(1));

    // Layer 1
    this.instance = new lib.myBlueCircle();
    this.instance.setTransform(70,60,1,1,0,0,0,20,20);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.instance, 0, 1, 1);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:230},9,cjs.Ease.get(1)).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(325,240,40,40);

})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

Comment: where is the defination of gotoAndPlay???

Comment: They're in here: https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js. I only added the relevant js above, not the entire html file. Check out the plunkr above to see it working so far.

Comment: ok please wait a moment

Comment: did you try commenting out this line stage.gotoAndPlay(1); from actionclickhandler??

Comment: That's the line I need to correct. I need to call gotoAndPlay(1) on the `stage` in `lib.bottomfile`. I need to do this from inside the function `actionclickhandler` . I can see `lib.bottomfile` it in the stack when I do `console.log(stage);` from inside the function, but I can't access it :(

Comment: I've solved it. `stage.children[0].gotoAndPlay("1");` Yay!

Comment: FYI, you can use a single stage, and add both of your export roots to the same stage (canvas). Additionally, instead of `stage.children[0]`, you can just access `exportRoot` and  `exportRoot2` directly, since they reference the content you added to the stage(s).

Comment: @Lanny I got it working in the end, this was a test for an expandable ad. How would I add both to the same stage? While still having control over each as it's own unit?

Comment: Each exportRoot is its own child if you use `stage.addChild(exportRoot, exportRoot2);`. Use the variable declarations (exportRoot, exportRoot1) instead of looking them up on the stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I changed the function `actionClickHandler` to:

```
function actionClickHandler() {  
     stage.children[0].gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

The way to access that timeline in `bottom.js` from the html file is by doing  `stage.children[0].`

[Here's a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gonIVDoSYDDObqxDJhAu?p=preview)